# Cannot add table in DBML designer with Foreign Key

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to add a small test table to the dbml designer, but it fails - nothing happends and there is no error message. The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Car]
(
    CarID       INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    CONSTRAINT  PK_Car PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    RegNo       VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    ModelID     INT NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_Car_Model FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Model (ModelID)
)
```

If I drop the FK_Car_Model constraint it works. Am I missing something about how the designer works with relations?

Comment: Works for me, both adding the Car table separately and adding both Car and Model table at the same time. Relation shows up in DBML designer. I guess your DBML is broken? Trying on VS2010 SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more than a year later, I came across the same situation again and this time it was solved by renaming a foreign key(!).

I have two tables `Cars` and `Persons`. `Cars` has a column `OwnerID` which is a reference to the owner. If the foreign key is named `FK_Car_Owner` it doesn't work. If the foreign key is renamed to `FK_Cars_Owner` it works.

Comment: You're awesome for coming back to it after so much time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I restarted Visual Studio. Not ideal, but much better than removing all the foreign keys.